# The value of an integrable function can be redefined at any finite number of points without changing the value of its integral.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

I am studying, "Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes, 3rd Edition", by Simmons and Finlay, and came across the following statement:

> The value of an integrable function can be redefined at any finite
>   number of points without changing the value of its integral.

I don't understand how this statement could be true.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to elaborate on this and convince me that it is true.

P.S. I have an elementary understanding of Riemann integration.

Comment: because for the integral of Riemann we have that $$\int_{(a,b)}f=\int_{[a,b]}f$$ You can see it from the formal definition of the integral of Riemann, based in the notion of Riemann sums (or Darboux sums). The intuition is that the integral represent the area under a curve.

Comment: @Masacroso Oh, I think I understand. It won't change the value of the integral since the integral (area) of (under) a point is $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an integral $\int_a^b f(x)\; dx$, where $f$ is Riemann integrable.  Let $g(x)$ be the same as $f(x)$ except at finitely many points $p_1, \ldots, p_m$, and $h(x) = g(x) - f(x)$.  Thus
$$h(x) = \cases{0 & if $x$ is not one of $p_1, \ldots, p_n$\cr
\text{something else} & if it is}$$
Let $B = \max_k |h(p_k)|$.  So
$$ \int_a^b g(x) \; dx = \int_a^b (f(x) + h(x))\; dx = \int_a^b f(x)\; dx + \int_a^b h(x)\; dx$$
But I claim $\int_a^b h(x) \; dx = 0$: if you take a Riemann sum $S = \sum_{j=1}^n h(\xi_j) \Delta x$, at most $m$ terms will be nonzero, and so
$ |S| \le m B \Delta x$.  As $n \to \infty$, $\Delta x \to 0$ and so $S \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Robert. Why do we have $h(x) = 0$ if $x$ is not one of $p_1,...,p_n$ and something else if it is? Should't it be the other way around? After all, $h(x) = 0$ only if $g(x) = f(x)$? Also, what is meant by $B = \max_k |h(p_k)|$?

Comment: Perhaps what you're missing is what "redefined at a finite number of points" means.  It means there are a finite number of points (here $p_1, \ldots, p_n$) where you change the value (i.e. where $g(x) \ne f(x)$, so $h(x) \ne 0$), and everywhere else you leave it the same ($g(x) = f(x)$, so $h(x) = 0$).

Comment: I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: if redefined function value of one point to $+\infty$, $B$ is still bounded?

Comment: @maplgebra Values of $\pm \infty$ are not allowed in Riemann integration.

Comment: Robert, did you mean take a Riemann sum $S= \sum_{i=1}^n h( \xi_i)\Delta x_i$ instead of Riemann sum of $f$?

Comment: @William Yes, thanks (edited).